# Calculate and store the total score for each student and calculate the average score for the whole class.

Tags: python

This is what I have done so far. Need help in finding the total score and average score.

```
name = ''
results = []
result = 0
question =1


while question <= 30:
    name = input("Enter student number "+str(question)+"'s name\n")
    result = input("Enter student number " + str(question) + "'s result\n")
    result =  int(result) #takes the var and makes it into int

    typeChecker = type(result) #checks the var type

    while typeChecker != int:
        result = input("Enter student number " + str(question) + "'s result\n")
        result =  int(result) #takes the var and makes it into int
    results += (name + result)

    print (results)

    question += 1
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming you are using Python 3)

You have a few issues.

```
result =  int(result) #takes the var and makes it into int

typeChecker = type(result) #checks the var type

while typeChecker != int:
    .
    .
```

This `while` is useless. The type of `result` can never be anything else than `int` by the time you check it. If the user inputted an invalid number then a `ValueError` would have been raised already without you catching it.

```
 results += (name + result)
```

This line has 2 problems. It will always raise a `TypeError` as it tries to concat a `str` and an `int`. Then it also tries to concat a `list` and whatever you expect the type of `name + result` to be. These are 2 `TypeError`s.

If you want to keep this simple, you should think about storing your data in a different container, perhaps a list of tuples where the first index is the name and the second is the score.

Then you can iterate over the list to calculate the sum and the average.